# Use "et al." for references with more than 3 authors

Tags: citing, natbib

I have to prepare a manuscript with the `llncs` document class. I must use "et al." for reference listings with more than 3 authors. I tried using the `natbib` package with the `\cite` command but i am not able to restrict the maximum number of authors to 3. Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please add a minimal example of what you have tried so far.  In particular, please tell us which bibliography style you are using.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting, to change the two instances of "et. al" to "et al.". Please clarify how entries with multiple authors should be formatted. For instance, if an entry has 5 authors, are you supposed to show the first three authors followed by "et al."? What about entries with exactly 4 authors? What about citation call-outs: Are they in numeric or in authoryear style? Please be specific.